# Order in which functions are invoked by doctest?

Tags: python, doctest

Im quite confused why `doctest.testmod()` is calling the test functions in a strange order

```
from doctest import testmod

def test_forwrite():
    '''
    >>> test_forwrite()
    OP: Done
    '''
    write()

def test_forread():
    '''
    >>> test_forread()
    OP: Done
    '''
    read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testmod(verbose = True)
```

Why regardless of the order in which its defined `test_forread()` gets tested first always.

Comment: Maybe because `test_forread` is alphabetically before `test_forwrite`? I doubt it cares/knows about the order the functions are defined.

Comment: Tests are supposed to be able to run *independently*, so why is any ordering at all strange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because the testmod function tests the functions in your given module/program by invoking them in **alphabetical** (sorted) order.

In your case `test_forread()` will be invoked first because it comes first before `test_forwrite()` when sorted in the alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2):

Tests are sorted by name. `test_forread` sorts before `test_forwrite()`, alphabetically.

From the [`doctest` source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9955f33cdbf27de270038dfbad37d15b160ecca2/Lib/doctest.py#L932-L938) for the [`DocTestFinder.find()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#doctest.DocTestFinder.find):

```
# Sort the tests by alpha order of names, for consistency in
# verbose-mode output.  This was a feature of doctest in Pythons
# <= 2.3 that got lost by accident in 2.4.  It was repaired in
# 2.4.4 and 2.5.
tests.sort()
```

`doctest.testmod()` [uses `DocTestFinder().find()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9955f33cdbf27de270038dfbad37d15b160ecca2/Lib/doctest.py#L1940-L1949) to locate the tests in your module.

Your tests should never rely on *any* given ordering, however. Write your tests to be independent, that way you could potentially run tests individually or in parallel.